# Create script tag with query string

Tags: javascript, html, query-string

I'm adding scripts to my `index.html` file dynamicly, when adding the scripts I also want to add a query string containing the file version.

for this I've done this

```
var src = 'app/core.js?201701051511',
    script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
console.info('src : ', src)
script.src = src;

script.async = true;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

However when I look in my browser console there's no querystring attached to the src of the generated scripts, how come?

Comment: I just try the code and there is the query string: That's the generated html, at the bottom of the head `<script type="text/javascript" src="app/core.js?201701051511" async=""></script>`

Comment: What shows up in your console?

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic) as it's not reproducible. Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query works as should. If console which you are using is trimming query, maybe it's just configured that way. Here is screenshot from Chrome on OS X.

[image]